# Did Paul Combetta ask for advice on reddit on how to strip emails for Hillary Clinton?

Tags: politics, government

A reddit user has several archived posts showing questions about stripping emails for a "VIP" customer.

Some people have attributed those posts to Paul Combetta, an employee in charge of Hillary Clinton's controversial email server, and conclude the "VIP" refers to Clinton.

[The Gateway Pundit](http://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2016/09/breaking-reddit-users-find-proof-hillarys-company-researching-delete-emails-without-trace/)

> According users on Reddit, Combetta asked for assistance in July 2014 from Reddit users on how to purge emails and how to strip VIP’s email address from “a bunch of archived emails.”

[The Political Insider](http://www.thepoliticalinsider.com/hillary-email-it-guy-caught-asked-destroy-evidence/)

> Paul Combetta, an IT specialist who helped Hillary Clinton wipe her server clean of evidence requested from federal authorities, took to online forums to find advice on how to commit the crime.

I see two distinct claims:

1. The reddit user asking those questions is Paul Combetta.
2. He used the information to remove Clinton's name from the emails.

Is there any evidence to support either of these claims?

Comment: *allegedly tied to* and *Some people have interpreted* I don't see much of a claim here. And what proof would be good enough?

Comment: @JanDoggen that was my attempt at remaining unbiased. An introduction to the story for those that are not familiar with it. In the links there are several posts describing why the user is Paul and what his responsibilities regarding the email issue were. Also, any evidence would be nice..

Comment: [This is being investigated](http://thehill.com/policy/national-security/296680-house-panel-probes-web-rumor-on-clinton-emails). For any real answer, we probably need to wait until the investigation completes. However, the gateway pundit claims that he asked for advise on how to delete emails, for which I can find no proof at all. My assumption is that they are misunderstanding something. Honestly, this seems like a bunch of nothing to me. No actual information was stripped, just the private email address of Clinton itself.

Comment: this probably counts as too much of a current events question. We may just have to wait and see how it all pans out.

Comment: [Confirmation of the investigation](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/09/20/house-panel-looking-into-reddit-post-linked-to-clintons-deleted-email/)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/exchangeserver/comments/2bmm4l/remove_or_replace_tofrom_address_on_archived/ and the actual Reddit conversation (with the question deleted along with the account that originated it).